# Css media queries questions

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi I created a sample site as practice...  why my < h3 id="art" > going down to footer section while shrinking my screen under 620 width and also, theres large space will show.. 
How to remove the space under footer and I dont want my words going to footer either

heres the sample site:  http://chess-master-guide-23476.bitballoon.com/views/main_page.html

Any solution?

Comment: post your code here.

Comment: Please isolate the issue, and mention the specific HTML/CSS code in the question for reference.

Comment: In the `#art`  id CSS selector change the `height:550px` to `min-height:550px` and see weather thats work's for you else try wrting media query for your whole page not just that portion of your page.

Comment: Your question is confusing, can you post your code or images showing your problem.?

Comment: I am sorry i should just post the codes here.  Thanks to @KawineshSK thats what i thought. Should write media query the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi there this is your css

```
#art {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #4c4c4c 0px, #595959 12%, #666 25%, #474747 39%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000 51%, #111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 572px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
```

you are using fixed height for this div this is the problem one.
and also you are using padding-left = 80px and padding-right = 200px;
its mean you need 280px only for padding for desktop or big screen it should be ok but for mobile or as you say less then 620px resolution you have 280px only for padding which is enough for mobile or less then 620px resolution.
secondly you are using fixed height for div id "art"
so that's why div is still remain as same size but text is increasing length because width is decreasing.
so you have two issues.
use height dynamic like

```
height: auto;
```

or don't use height property then height will be populate with elements
or use media query for different devices.
it should be solve your problem. now your text wont go down.
but padding still push your text in short length lines so you have to adjust your padding also.
like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

hope this helps you.
thanks

here is a image i just change

height: auto;

this image is from device simulator with 320X640

[image]

Comment: I took a part of your advice and set as  #art {
 
                       height: auto ;
                       width: 300px; 
                }   it worked perfectly thx :)